# Implosion calculations

Tags: fluid-dynamics

I am working on a home project and I wanted to learn some required calculations.
How do I calculate the point of implosive failure for a tank given a certain material with a variable internal pressure.

For example if I were to use Steel vs carbon fiber.
For simplicity lets say the object was at an altitude that allowed for an outside psi of 12 and an internal pressure was set at 8 psi.
Assuming a 10 foot sphere if needed.

Comment: I may have over constrained my question. The 8 psi can be reduced as needed.

Comment: Can't answer, but FYI: When a vessel collapses because of external pressure, that's an example of [_buckling_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buckling). I get the impression from somewhere that it's a pretty deep subject.

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/769650/226902 and ["Analysis of the possibility of a submarine implosion using finite element method" (2021)](https://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1088/1742-6596/2130/1/012006).